# Structural geology book to make an app for first courses students

Tags: structural-geology

I want to make a structural geology app for first courses geology and minning students.

I want a book that list the structures as folds and faults to do my own designs with [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Can you recommend me a book (in English, French or Spanish)?